# Integral domain which contains a copy of its fraction field

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, integral-domain

Let $R$ be an integral domain with fraction field $K$. If there exists an injective ring homomorphism from $K$ to $R$ , then is it true that $R$ is a field ?

Strictly speaking, I am not saying $K \subseteq R$ and the injective map say $\phi : K \to R$ could possibly be anything, so I am not quite sure whether this really does imply $R$ is a field or not (I feel it should ... )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $(x_n)_{n\ge0}$ be a sequence of algebraically independent indeterminates over the field $F$ and let $K=F(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n,\dotsc)$. Consider $R=K[x_0]$, which is not a field. Its fraction field is $F(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n,\dotsc)\cong K$.

Comment: And if restricting to isomorphisms of $k$-algebra and $Frac(R)$ is finitely generated as a field extension of $k$ then $Frac(R) \cong S \subset R$ implies $R$ is a field. Assuming $\overline{Frac(R)} = \overline{F}$ with $F/k$ finitely generated should work too.

Comment: @reuns Agreed; if the embedding $K\to R$ should be sensible, then the example above cannot work.